# retaining original object for end of map and filter chain

Tags: lambda, java-8

given the following code

```
List<Double> radia = Arrays.asList(1.0, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9);
List<Ball> listOfBalls = new ArrayList<>();        
radia.forEach(radius -> listOfBalls.add(new Ball(radius)));

listOfBalls.stream().map(b -> b.getVolume())
                        .filter(d -> d>10)
                        .forEach(d -> pprint(d));
```

How do I retain which Ball is being printed in the last forEach?
I would like to be able to print something like

```
"Ball with radius " b.getRadius() + " has volume" + d
```

Comment: you cannot with the above data model. You can do it by creating a new field in Ball called volume and setting that in the map function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As lambdas cannot assign to variables outside of their scope, you would have to use an object in the higher scope in order to store the result.

A note is that this is not the intended use of lambdas or the streams API. If you're seeking a single final result, you should use `findFirst` or `findAny` like so:

```
listOfBalls.stream().map(Ball::getVolume)
                        .filter(d -> d>10)
                        .findFirst();
```

If you're looking for a `List` of `Balls` then use `Collectors.toList()` like so:

```
List<Ball> result = listOfBalls.stream().map(Ball::getVolume)
                        .filter(d -> d>10)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

At that point you can then iterate through the list and output what you'd like. Streams are consumed upon operation, which means you cannot use them after you've called `forEach`, lists are not bound by this restriction.

Comment: thank you for the great answer. Even though this does not help me(it does not solve my problem of eliminating possible expensive calls multiple times), it is the correct answer(it solves my question)

Comment: @ShadowFlame where did you say that your problem is “eliminating possible expensive calls multiple times”? And what “expensive calls” are you talking about?

Comment: @Holger: I din't, which is also what you can deduce from my comment. 
In this example I don't have expensive calls, but that does not mean that a project that I may or may not have does not have them...

Comment: @ShadowFlame then, why did you made that comment about this answer not solving a problem you didn’t mention before and now admit to not even having? What was your comment supposed to tell the reader?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by **not mapping** each `Ball` to its volume, yet filtering as you need:

```
listOfBalls.stream()
    .filter(b -> b.getVolume() > 10)
    .forEach(b -> System.out.println(
         "Ball with radius " + b.getRadius() + " has volume " + b.getVolume()));
```

---

**EDIT** as per [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49275807/retaining-original-object-for-end-of-map-and-filter-chain/49282031?noredirect=1#comment85590320_49282031):

If invoking the `Ball.getVolume` method twice is not desirable (either due to an expensive computation or a to DB access), you could pass the result of that method along with the corresponding `Ball` instance down the stream. If you are on Java 9+:

```
listOfBalls.stream()
    .map(b -> Map.entry(b, b.getVolume())) // perform expensive call here
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 10)
    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(
         "Ball with radius " + e.getKey().getRadius() + " has volume " + b.getValue()));
```

If you are on Java 8, you can use `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(...)` instead of `Map.entry(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer as well, however, this is some code I had as well. The problem here is that b.getVolume is executed twice for each filtered result. While that is no big deal for calculating the volume of a ball, it matters when doing expensive computations/DB access/....
Now that I understand the possibilities, I'll have to decide case-by-case what my solution will be.